# how to get rid of this error : ./1.sh: 13: ./1.sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: command-line, scripts

I am running following shell script :

```
#! /bin/sh

authToken=`curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"username","password":"password","recaptcha":""}' https://myurl`

curl -G "https://my-url-path?auth=$authToken" --output output.json
c=`grep -o "Hotfix[0-9]*" output.json | grep -o "[0-9]*" | awk 'n < $0 {n=$0}END{print n}'

curl "https://my-url-path/Hotfix$c/file$c.tar.bz2?auth=$authToken" --output file.tar.bz2
docker load < file.tar.bz2
```

and i am getting the following error :

```
./1.sh: 13: ./1.sh: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

Comment: The line beginning `c=` is missing its closing backtick